# JQ: combine arrays into single string

Tags: json, jq

Here is my json file. I would like to get string "c,d,e,f,g,h" using JQ query.

```
{
    "a1": [
      {
        "group_sourceId": "monday",
        "ids": ["a", "b"]
      },
      {
        "group_sourceId": "sunday",
        "ids": ["c", "d"]
      },
      {
        "group_sourceId": "sunday",
        "ids": ["e", "f"]
      },
      {
        "group_sourceId": "sunday",
        "ids": ["g", "h"]
      }
    ],
    "m1": [
      {
        "group_sourceId": "sunday"
      },
      {
        "group_sourceId": "sunday"
      }
    ]
}
```

This is what I tried.

**cat /tmp/example.json  | jq -r '.a1[] | select(.group_sourceId | startswith("sunday")) | .ids'**

returns

```
[
  "c",
  "d"
]
[
  "e",
  "f"
]
[
  "g",
  "h"
]
```

then

**cat /tmp/example.json  | jq -r '.a1[] | select(.group_sourceId | startswith("sunday")) | .ids | join(",")'**

```
c,d
e,f
g,h
```

How to get "c,d,e,f,g,h" as a output considering there could be any number of "ids" in "a1" object and any number of strings in "ids" array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using `map`. Also, you could use `==` to test for an exact match.

```sh
jq -r '.a1 | map(select(.group_sourceId == "sunday").ids[]) | join(",")'
```

```json
c,d,e,f,g,h
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RBq9p5xQFP)

Answer (score 1):

`[.a1[] | select(.group_sourceId | startswith("sunday")) | .ids[]] | sort[]`

produces the sorted listing.  If you want the unique values, use `unique` instead of `sort`.  If you want the output as a line of CSV, you could replace the final `[]` with `| @csv`.